# Are React Private Routes really secure?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, react-router

I'd like to create a custom blog using React as frontend with an admin panel to write the articles and so on.

I've been researching this and I saw that I can make some routes private, 'myblog.com/admin' to access the dashboard if the user (admin) is authenticated with the backend, etc.

However, that dashboard would be still in the client browser, either way is authenticated or not. If a hacker or whoever modifies the JavaScript, it could jump over the authentication and access to the dashboard and write a post through the API, couldn't it? Maybe the solution is, every time an admin uses the API I authenticate who's sending it in the server-side, or maybe I got lost in how this should work.

I'm new in web development.

Answer (score 1):

No! It is not secure, you are using client side code and everyone can see/modify your client code.

You need to handle all admin request on your api and check if user is really admin.

Or dedicate your admin site to special url/server.

Once again:
Validation on client side is fine, but you need to validate on API.

Comment: So, I might do what I was thinking, working with react private routes but always validating the admin on the API. Everything should be fine with that, or is there anything else I should pay attention to?

Comment: @FernandoEP As you said. Maybe... I can edit your source code and I can see wich options you can set for users in admin section (of course I can't change it - because you are handling this on API, but I can see it).